# Проблема с графическим редактором XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть `Behavior`(код взят с интернета):

```
public class PasswordBoxBindingBehavior : Behavior<PasswordBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += OnPasswordBoxValueChanged;
    }

    public SecureString Password
    {
        get { return (SecureString)GetValue(PasswordProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Password", typeof(SecureString), typeof(PasswordBoxBindingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    private void OnPasswordBoxValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, PasswordProperty);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = binding.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty(binding.ParentBinding.Path.Path);
            if (property != null)
                property.SetValue(binding.DataItem, AssociatedObject.SecurePassword, null);
        }
    }
}
```

И его использование:

```
<PasswordBox Grid.Column="1"
             FontFamily="Comic Sans MC"
             FontSize="25">
         <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
             <pas:PasswordBoxBindingBehavior Password="{Binding Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
         </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <PasswordBox.ToolTip>
             <TextBlock FontSize="20">Password</TextBlock>
         </PasswordBox.ToolTip>
</PasswordBox>
```

В результате все компилируется и работает хорошо, но визуальный редактор Xaml выдает вот такую ошибку:

> The type 'PasswordBoxBindingBehavior' from assembly
>   'MessengerClient' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and
>   is not supported in a Windows Presentation Framework 4 project.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А откуда у вас `Behavior`? Это может быть проблемой.

Comment: @VladD, `Behavior` взят из этой статьи http://briannoyesblog.azurewebsites.net/2015/03/04/wpf-using-passwordbox-in-mvvm/

Comment: Не, я имел в виду не `PasswordBoxBindingBehavior`, а базовый класс `Behavior`. Может быть, он из устаревшей библиотеки.

Comment: @VladD, библиотека `System.Windows.Interactivity Version 4.5.0.0`. Вроде бы новее версии нету.

Comment: @VladD, Единственная существенная разница которую я нашел в сравнении с статьей автора, это то что у него `.Net`версии `4.5`, а у меня `4.5.2`. Может быть из-за этого проблема?

Comment: @VladD, У меня `VS 2015 Update 2`, попробовал запустить тот же проект на другом ПК с `VS 2015` и данная проблема не появилась.

Comment: Хм, странно. А операционка та же?

Comment: @VladD, Да, операционки на обоих ПК одинаковые - `Win10 x64`.

Comment: Кажется, это похоже на ваш случай: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32024034/276994

Comment: @VladD, Этот способ я уже пробовал, не помогло :(